# How to handle yii2 migrations on hosts without console access?

Tags: php, migration, yii2

I've succesfully created and uploaded advanced template on my shared host.

As next step, I must run the `yii migrate`.

But I cannot because I've not the console access.

What could you suggest to me?

Please note that

- I cannot change the host, because it's not a decision of mine
- I cannot access the server using SSH
- I've already tried something like PHPShell, but I got `permissione denied` when trying to run`yii migrate --interactive=0`

I tried also this: added an actionMigrateUp to `frontend/controllers/siteController.php`

```
public function actionMigrateUp()
{
    // https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1764#issuecomment-42436905
    $oldApp = \Yii::$app;
    new \yii\console\Application([
        'id'            => 'Command runner',
        'basePath'      => '@app',
        'components'    => [
            'db' => $oldApp->db,
        ],
    ]);
    \Yii::$app->runAction('migrate/up', ['migrationPath' => '@console/migrations/', 'interactive' => false]);
    \Yii::$app = $oldApp;
}
```

But when I visit `/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/migrateUp` I got a 404

> exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to
>   resolve the request: site/migrateUp' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php:122

Comment: Have you tried connecting to server using SSH and then executing command in your project directory?

Comment: I've NO SSH access. It was this I meant saying "no console access"

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1764#issuecomment-42436905

Comment: @EvgeniyTkachenko: thanks, see my updated question, I've tried without results, seems that runAction cannot identify 'migrate/up' .. or something of similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The action that you have created is not accesible with

```
/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/migrateUp
```

but with

```
/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/migrate-up
```

Otherwise everything should be fine.

Comment: Ok, I've approved and voted up your reply. By, of course, I'll re-open the question because the question was how to handle migrations; sorry.

Comment: They still do not work? I have done this in yii1 and it works ok

Comment: No, it still not works, I really need a tutorial for yii 2 on this argument. I'll do a lot of work next monday, next I'll post my question again

Comment: I see you have tried what samdark said, but have you tried what stepanselyuk did bellow? He created a full helper just for that.

Comment: Also take into consideration that what they built is for the basic template, you might have to change some variables around to fit the advance template that you are using.

Comment: Sorry, which helper? Could you provide me  a link? @MihaiP

Comment: This post and the 3 below tell you how to do it with a full example: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1764#issuecomment-54537675

Comment: @MihaiP. Will this timeout if the query takes more time to execute than the max timeout limit?