# execute migrations script in a yii2 web application

Tags: yii2

I'm building a web application using yii2 framework. I've installed the yii2-admin extension, and I want to use the menu manager functions.

In the official documentations it's said to apply the migrations:

```
yii migrate --migrationPath=@mdm/admin/migrations
```

How can I execute that migration in a web application? Is there some actions to call?

Comment: So you want to execute it with page load and not with console?

Comment: yes, because I have no console access

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983169/how-to-handle-yii2-migrations-on-hosts-without-console-access

Comment: But look at the answer on the very bottom of the comment section. As that links to the proper part of how you can build that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [extension](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension)

```
"vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension": "*"
```

Usage

```
use vova07\console\ConsoleRunner;
$cr = new ConsoleRunner(['file' => '@my/path/to/yii']);
$cr->run('controller/action param1 param2 ...');
```

Application component:

```
// config.php
...
components [
    'consoleRunner' => [
        'class' => 'vova07\console\ConsoleRunner',
        'file' => '@my/path/to/yii' // or an absolute path to console file
    ]
]
...

// some-file.php
Yii::$app->consoleRunner->run('controller/action param1 param2 ...');
```