# Deploying Yii2 app to shared host steps

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I find it bizarre that there is so little, (if any) details on considerations for deploying a Yii2 app to a shared host server.

Does anyone have some steps, tips, considerations for this ?

Is there a process you follow that keeps issues/errors down to a minimum ?

How does the DB get migrated (with data)? I'm assuming I could do export/import of the DB, copy the Yii app folder directly, but that seems too simplistic ?

Comment: It's no more complicated than you have said. Just migrate the db, copy your folders, change the config to suit the new environment and you're done.

Comment: did you read this page? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html

Comment: @JoeMiller migrating the db (with data) is my biggest concern - any pointers ? steps ?

Comment: It's really no big deal, just import/export from mysql. Phpmyadmin makes this a lot easier.

Comment: I am trying to upload my `yii2 application` but unable to do it. I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66988294/6854117) can you please see it ?

Answer (score 2):

First read this page http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html

Regarding the files yes, just copy them. If your host allows you ssh access (but not git) you can have them copied very fast with rsync (so you can use composer etc on your computer and deploy through ssh). I have done a similar script that does the same thing with FTP at 1 point but it was much slower. Since I have stopped making websites for shared hosting.

Regarding the migrations you can make them run from the browser too for example [How to handle yii2 migrations on hosts without console access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983169/how-to-handle-yii2-migrations-on-hosts-without-console-access)
Make sure you read the answer and the comments too and follow that link.

Comment: Thx for those links - the first one is decent albeit brief, but my larger concern is with migrating the DB (with data), so will go thru the 2nd link soon

Comment: The migrations you will do 1 time (the scripts that migrate anyway), have it working and that will be it. Then you will realize that copying the files over is actually the bigger problem.

Comment: oh i see, thx for the heads up. Side question in regards to DB - can you just do export/import from MySql ?

Comment: you can but migrations are easier, you do not have to care if anything changed on the server db while doing your changes etc. It is a much, much cleaner way of doing things.

Comment: migrations  always  have an edge they are like version control for your schema i agree with @MihaiP.

Comment: I am trying to upload my `yii2 application` but unable to do it. I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66988294/6854117) can you please see it ?