# Deploying Yii2 into shared hosting, Directly to basic template folder

Tags: php, deployment, yii2

I have read the doc from Yii2 official website to deploy yii2 into share host from this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html, and about discussion on this : [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110415/deploying-yii2-app-to-shared-host-steps).

So, I decide to use sftp to upload the yii2 folder.
And this is the list of directory in my share host.

```
access-logs
etc
logs
public_ftp
public_html
ssl
www (this is a link folder to public_html)
```

You know, because the share host can hold on domains untill 5 domains,
is it possible to upload yii2basic folder into public_html folder ?

So the result like this :

```
access-logs
etc
logs
public_ftp
public_html
    -basic
        - bunch of yii folders here
ssl
www (this is a link folder to public_html)
```

Because now, if I want to access my web, I have to write like this : `mydomain.com/basic/public_html/index.php`

I need like this :

```
mydomain.com/index.php
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Have you got the ability to make `public_html` a symlink to other folder?

Comment: By default on provider, 'www' folder is symlink to public_html

Comment: This is not what I asked...

Comment: well this is the simplest yii deployment guide on cloud server and you can easily create a web root path to serve your app from domain.com. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/install-yii-2-framework-on-cloud/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upload it inside the `public_html` folder but the only problem that I have been facing nowadays with yii2 basic app is the pretty URLs, you can clone or upload entire contents inside the `public_html` folder, what I did is as follows only the difference is I have a `web` folder instead of `www`

directory structure

```
public_html
  assets
  commands
  config
  controller
  mail
  migrations
  models
  runtime
  tests
  vendor
  views
  web
```

public_html/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

public_html/web/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

this works but in the URL it shows `/web/index.php?r=site/index` and as soon as I turn the `prettyUrl` on in the config file `urlManager` it would only show default index page and every link I try to open ends up on the home page view although the URL in the address bar is correct and urlManager parses the rules correctly, this is as far as I have gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind bunch of Yii 2 folders in your root folder just place all basic template folders (except `web`) and files in the root folder. Then place the content of `web` folder in the `public_html` folder.

It should be something like:

```
access-logs
assets
commands
config
controllers
etc
logs
mail
models
public_ftp
public_html
    // here should be the content of web folder of Yii 2 basic app
runtime
ssl
test
views
widgets
```