# installing yii2 on a host that does not allow placing files outside of the htdocs folder

Tags: security, installation, yii, shared-hosting, yii2-basic-app

The problem is, as the title mentions, how to install yii2 on a hosting that does not allow files to be placed outside the htdocs folder.

the hosting is byhost: not allow files to be placed outside the htdocs folder.

what alternatives do I have?

We know that for security most of the folders of a yii2 app should go outside of the htdocs folder, so what can I do to prevent people from having access to these folders or redirect any attempt to access for example the config, vendor folder? , etc?

For example, when you enter the browser and write www.my_app.com/vendor, all the files that that folder contains are listed.

What do you suggest?

Actually I have not tried anything and I can not think of what I can do, I have searched for information but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by following this post.

[Deploying Yii2 into shared hosting, Directly to basic template folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763733/deploying-yii2-into-shared-hosting-directly-to-basic-template-folder)

The solution is an htaccess file, in the root of the htdocs folder and another htaccess file in the web folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The real solution was to use the kartik practical-b skeletal template that is adapted for what I wanted.
The files and folders were carefully organized to perform the installation in the webroot.

I hope it is useful for someone.