# Steps to host Yii2 application on shared server using cpanel (godaddy)

Tags: php, yii, cpanel, yii2-advanced-app, shared-hosting

I have yii2 app ready, next I moved to host on server.
I am using cpanel of godaddy where one site of wordpress already running on root.
I did as here [Deploying Yii2 app to shared host steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110415/deploying-yii2-app-to-shared-host-steps)
Here is what i did so far-

1. Created one folder as subfile there.
2. uploaded zip code base there and extract there.
3. Created user in mysql.
4. Created database of application.
5. Imported data to the database(New).
6. Made changes in config file for dbConnection.
7. made changes in .htaccess for main and frontend/web.
   I have seen these all links--

   > This page isn’t working
   >   domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
   >   HTTP ERROR 500

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-shared-hosting.md
This is not clear- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/827/how-to-install-yii-2-advanced-on-a-shared-hosting-environment/
[does't make it clear](https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tutorial-shared-hosting/)

Help me please.

Comment: You can check cPanel error log for more details about the problem.
Go to cPanel and towards the bottom you will see 'error logs'.

Comment: i saw that, there was issue  /myapp/public_html/web/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.xhtml....], I made changes in htaccess and it gone, now no error there.

Comment: I also check for 'http://example.com/web/requirements.php', there is no error but have few warning, remaining all passed.

Comment: I changed in Subdomains.Root and document Root, now now getting 'Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.' there...

Comment: I am Also faced same issues for godaddy share hosting server.

Comment: In my case I have WordPress  website which is running fine. now I want to access my Yii website to work inside sub-directory .

Comment: I am trying to upload my `yii2 application` but unable to do it. I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66988294/6854117) can you please see it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm super-lazy and I'm knowing it .htaccess is slower (as far as I know). With clients, who ask shared hosting - this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend)/web/ - [L]

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ backend/web/$2 [S=1]

# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/$0

# Uncomment the following, if you want speaking URL
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+/web)/.*$ $1/index.php

# If mod_expires (set headers for some stuff)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 </IfModule>
```

So - basically you get [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) as frontend and */admin as backend (If you're using advanced template)

EDIT - Sorry, forgot this:
In frontend/config/main.php

```
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
            'baseUrl' => '/',
        ],
```

and backend/config/main.php

```
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
            'baseUrl' => '/admin',
        ],
```