# How do I clear and migrate the database automatically for testing?

Tags: testing, yii, yii2, codeception

I am building an API with Yii2 and have some codeception API tests working with a test database. However I would like to clear and migrate the database on each round of testing.

How do I go about this? I can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Don't know exactly how it is supposed to work what your doing but wouldn't it be that easy as creating some action inside a controller that will run a big sql file that drops all tables and creates them again? Then before your tests you just call that page.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a better, less hacky way to do it. Also, adding a controller action to flush the database sounds very risky.

Comment: Other ideas: for the hacky way in order to secure it you can pass a token in the url, or limit to local ip. I saw Yii also has Fixtures not sure if they are of any use for you, and in the last place, since you mention codeception here it describes quite what you want to do: http://codeception.com/docs/09-Data

Answer (score 3):

Yii migrations are designed to do exactly what you want. There is full documentation about creating them [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html). The downside is that you need access to the command line. If you don't have this you can still use migrations, but you need to create a new instance of a console application. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983169/how-to-handle-yii2-migrations-on-hosts-without-console-access) for a discussion of exactly this problem.

As for the risk of having a controller action flush the database, I agree it can be risky, but you can limit the action to only admin users using rules, and maybe even use a form to initiate the action to you can use csrf tokens to validate the submission, and only allow the action via the post method. If you need some guidance on doing this I can update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I am using (and love) migrations and want them to run automatically when I run tests. I worked on a Laravel project for some months and each test file would start with a fresh database (populated with specific fixtures). I would like to replicate that in Yii2 but not sure how. I think for now I will create a controller action to remove and migrate the database for each test file.

Comment: Actually, I don't need a controller action for this. I'll write a custom method that can be called to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of testing an API, reverting the content of the database to a certain state can surely be done using migrations, but I don't think that's the best solution you can have, the solution for this should be using *Fixtures*.

See more information about fixtures in the official documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-test-fixtures.html

Once you've implemented the fixtures (should be quite straightforward, otherwise just open another post) you'll probably realise that migrations might actually be needed anyway to keep the database structure in sync.

This task can either be done manually by the developer before committing to create any test, or automatically if you have a CI server.

Once again, migrations are not needed to be run every time you run a test, just at the beginning. Fixtures are what you need to bring the database to a certain status during any type of test.

Comment: I do intend to use fixtures but some tests require the creation of models to test the workflow of creation, authentication, authorisation and relationships. If I add users in one test, I don't want it affecting other tests that may be expecting a certain number of users (or other model) for example.

Comment: And when I say migrations, I mean that I want to have the database automatically upgraded to the latest migration rather than doing it manually.

Comment: @Dubby I think there's a bit of confusion: this is really down to the way you're organising your work and codebase. The features you're developing should be self contained if you want the tests to run separately and not impact any other's work. As I was explaining, you *do* need migrations but these are needed only at the very beginning before running the tests: in a normal Continuous Integration system the migrations would be run automatically. Codeception that runs the tests is not aware of Yii and its migrations infrastructure, so this situation is quite expected. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @The_Peach. Yes, I understand this and will probably add some code to tests/_bootstrap.php to check for migrations, hoping it will only run once when executing tests. I like the term `self contained`. How do I achieve that? Records added in one test are not removed at the end. This is my API test that is not clearing out the values: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe05253bf0364cde349b

Comment: @Dubby fixtures are what you're looking for, see the answer above for more information on how to set them up. Fixtures are the only way to control the content of the db for tests.